# Add generic model to helper class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have the following code to generate selectlistitems to show in my dropdownlist.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems(this IEnumerable<BlogCategory>    categories, int selectedId)
    {
        return categories.OrderBy(category => category.Category)
            .Select(category => new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = (category.ID == selectedId),
                Text = category.Category,
                Value = category.ID.ToString()
            });
    }
```

I want to use this helper class to generate other list items then BlogCategory. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a base class for your lookup entities:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Title {get;set;}
}

public class Category : BaseEntity
{
   //Category fields
}

public class Blog : BaseEntity
{
   //Blog fields
}  

public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems(this IEnumerable<BaseEntity> entityList, int selectedId)
{
    return entityList.OrderBy(q => q.Title)
        .Select(q => new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = (q.Id == selectedId),
            Text = q.Title,
            Value = q.Id.ToString()
        });
}
```

Comment: efe - great minds. i was about to post my take on this using interfaces rather than a base class

Answer (score 2):

Jurgen,

**ASSUMING** you are meaning that the other list items all conform to the same structure as BlogCategory, then you can use an interface, rather than a concrete class in your helper.

Here's how that might look:

```
public interface ICategory
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Category { get; set; }
}

public class BlogCategory : ICategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
} 

public class PostCategory : ICategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

etc, etc.. then use your other classes against this interface as required using your existing helper class along the lines of:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems
    (this IEnumerable<ICategory> categories, int selectedId)
{
    return categories.OrderBy(category => category.Category)
        .Select(category => new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = (category.ID == selectedId),
            Text = category.Category,
            Value = category.ID.ToString()
        });
}
```

enjoy...